# is there a way to integrate asp.net web API with swagger2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

There is a full support of swagger in spring boot. so here how can we achieve this with asp.net web API?

Answer (score 0):

For C# Web Api, you can use [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle).

Comment: We should not encourage `only link` answers. please provide more information and code snippets. Also step by step guide would help. Your current answer would better suit for to be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) to enable Swagger 2.0 on my APIs.

Nuget package:

```
Install-Package Swashbuckle
```

After you install Swashbuckle it will automatically create a file called SwaggerConfig.cs under your App_Start folder in your project.  This file uses WebActivatorEx to automatically run the code you see in there on application startup.  If you look at this file it is becomes pretty straight forward to see how and what they are doing.

After you have this installed on your application you can open the following url to see your swagger UI: ~/swagger/ui/index

If you are interested in seeing the Swagger 2.0 JSON it creates you can navigate to ~/swagger/docs/v1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should also have a look at [NSwag](http://nswag.org): The project combines the functionality of Swashbuckle (Swagger generation) and AutoRest (client generation) in one tool chain.

The tool can be integrated in the build process or directly in an Web API action method.